# pass parameter to the woocommerce search product

Tags: java, php, http-post, woocommerce

Im trying to pass parameter from java applet page into php page, specifically in the theme-woocommerce.php . The Java page will involve the process of sending the specific keyword into the theme-woocommerce.php .

**For example:**

User will input the sentence ***"I want to buy Blue Jersey"***.
the user will click ***"Send" button***
The java part will process and get the keyword ***"Blue Jersey"***

And then at the same time, ***"Blue Jersey"*** Keyword will be send
into the php page using the http-post.

the problem here that im facing now is that i dont really know
how and where should i put the post array in the php page.

***Here is the java part to pass the parameter to php page:***

```
try {  



                String data2 = URLEncoder.encode("keyword", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(system.askquestion(instring,outstring,getkeyword)[1], "UTF-8"); 
                String data =    data2 ;  

                String inLine;  

                URL u1 = new URL("http://localhost/echo.php");  
                URLConnection uc1 = u1.openConnection();  

                uc1.setDoOutput(true);  
                OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(uc1.getOutputStream());  
                out.write(data); 
                out.flush();  

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( uc1.getInputStream() ) );  

                while ((inLine = in.readLine()) != null) {  
                    System.out.println(inLine);  
                }  

                in.close();  
            }  
            catch( Exception E ) {  
                E.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }
        return false;
    }
```

***This one is the theme-woocommerce.php code:***

```
<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" class="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url();?>">
        <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"><?php _e('Search for:', 'woothemes'); ?></label>
        <input type="text" value="<?php the_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s"  class="field s" placeholder="<?php _e('Search for products', 'woothemes'); ?>" />
        <input type="image" class="submit btn" name="submit" value="<?php _e('Search', 'woothemes'); ?>" src="<?php echo get_template_directory_uri(); ?>/images/ico-search.png">
        <?php if ($woo_options['woo_header_search_scope'] == 'products' ) { echo '<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />'; } else { echo '<input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="post" />'; } ?>
    </form>
    <div class="fix"></div>
```

***Here are my Questions:***

1. Is it possible for me to pass the parameter to theme-woocommerce.php
2. How and where should i put **$_POST["keyword"]** in theme-woocommerce.php
3. Is it possible for me to use the function search where the input is receive from java page.

   public boolean handleEvent(Event e)
       { 
           String instring, outstring,getkeyword = null ;
           if ((( e.target instanceof TextField ) || ( e.target instanceof Button )) &&
                   ( e.id == Event.ACTION_EVENT )) 
           {
               instring    = questions.getText();

   ```
           outstring   = new String();
           if ( instring.length() > 0 ) {
               answer.appendText("\nYou: " + instring + "\n" );
               answer.appendText( "Faris: " + system.askquestion(instring,outstring,getkeyword) [0] + "\n" );

           questions.setText(" ");
       }
        if ( e.target instanceof Button ) {
            questions.requestFocus();
           }

        String truee = URLEncoder.encode(system.askquestion(instring , outstring, getkeyword)[1], "UTF-8");
        String formURL = "http://localhost/echo.php"; // this should be whatever home_url() in PHP returns
        URL url = new URL(formURL + "?s=" + truee); // s because there is <input ... name="s"...> in the form
        InputStream inputStream = url.openStream();
        try {
            // ... process the returned response
        } finally {
            inputStream.close();
        }
   ```

***This is the whole java Coding***

```
import java.applet.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataInputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.net.*;
import java.io.*;


import javax.swing.JPanel;



  public class VirtualAssistant extends Applet   {
//Declare the variables
    Image poster;
    Button askButton;
    TextField questions;
    TextArea answer;
    String newline;
    boolean     inited      = false;

    Responder   system;







    String      responderfile    = new String( "VirtualAssistant.dat" );



    public void init(){
         if ( !inited ) {




                try {
                    system  = new Responder( getDocumentBase(), responderfile );
                } catch ( IOException e ) {
                    System.out.println( "Can't open response file [" +
                        responderfile + "]" );
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }



                setSize(330,500);
        //Tell the applet not to use a layout manager. 
        setLayout(null);

        //Get image file
        poster=getImage(getDocumentBase(), "avatar.jpg");


        //create an object for textfield and button
        this.questions = new TextField(300);

        this.answer = new TextArea("Faris: I'm the Virtual Assistant. How can I help you?");
        answer.setEditable( false );

        this.askButton = new Button("Ask Me");



        //this.answerBox = new text(20);

         //add the button to the layout
         this.add(questions);
         this.add(answer);
         this.add(askButton);

         //Position of TextField and Button
         questions.setBounds(20,270,240,25); 
         answer.setBounds(20,300,290,200);
         askButton.setBounds(260,270,50,25); 


         /*RespondsQuestions = new TextArea( "Welcome to Dialogue Based Train Information System. How may I help you?\n", 20, 150 );
         RespondsQuestions.setEditable( true );*/

         //
         //askButton.addActionListener(this);
         questions.requestFocus();

            inited  = true;
         }
    }

    public void paint (Graphics g){
        Font font = new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 12);
         int height = font.getSize();

            g.setFont(font);


        //set image image width and height
        int imagewidth = 250;
        int imageheight = 250;

        //Positioning text and image
        g.drawImage(poster,15,30,imagewidth,imageheight,this);
        g.drawString("How Can I Help You?",180,130);
        g.drawString("Chatting with Virtual Assistant",60,20);

        //g.drawString(AskQuestions.getText(),20,100); 
    }



    public boolean handleEvent(Event e)  
    { 
        String instring, outstring,getkeyword = null ;
        if ((( e.target instanceof TextField ) || ( e.target instanceof Button )) &&
                ( e.id == Event.ACTION_EVENT )) 
        {
            instring    = questions.getText();

            outstring   = new String();
            if ( instring.length() > 0 ) {
                answer.appendText("\nYou: " + instring + "\n" );
                answer.appendText( "Faris: " + system.askquestion(instring,outstring,getkeyword) [0] + "\n" );

            questions.setText(" ");
        }
         if ( e.target instanceof Button ) {
             questions.requestFocus();
            }
         try {  


                //String data1 = URLEncoder.encode("answer", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(system.askquestion(instring,outstring,getkeyword)[0], "UTF-8");  
                String encodedKW = URLEncoder.encode("keyword", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(system.askquestion(instring,outstring,getkeyword)[1], "UTF-8"); 
                String keywords;
                String data =   encodedKW ;  

                String inLine;  

                URL u1 = new URL("http://localhost/echo.php");
                //URL u1 = new URL("http://smartjersionline.owhbisnes.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-template.php" + "?s=" + encodedKW );  
                URLConnection uc1 = u1.openConnection();  

                uc1.setDoOutput(true);  
                OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(uc1.getOutputStream());  
                out.write(data); 
                out.flush();  

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( uc1.getInputStream() ) );  

                while ((inLine = in.readLine()) != null) {  
                    System.out.println(inLine);  
                }  

                in.close();  
            }  
            catch( Exception E ) {  
                E.printStackTrace();  
            }  
        }


        return false;
    }









    public static void main( String args[] ) {
        Frame f         = new Frame( "Virtual Assistant/Application" );
        VirtualAssistant session   = new VirtualAssistant();

        session.init();








    }


    class Responder {



        String[] replies    = new String[ 600 ];
        String[] keywords   = new String[ 400 ];
        String  previous    = new String();         // previous question
        int keyword;                                // index into keyword array
        int numkeys;                                // total number of keys read in
        int maxkey          = 0;                    // number of keywords
        int minreply        = 0;                    // first reply for current keyword.
        int maxreply        = 0;                    // last reply for current keyword





        int[] first         = new int[ 400 ];       // first reply for keyword number in subscript.
        int[] last          = new int[ 400 ];       // last reply   "     "      "     "     "    .
        int[] offset        = new int[ 400 ];       // offset from first reply for each keyword.




        String  trace       = new String();

        Responder( URL baseURL, String respfile ) throws IOException {
            InputStream     file;
            DataInputStream dis;
            String          line;
            int             numkeys;
            boolean         isreply = false;

            file    = ( new URL( baseURL, respfile )).openStream();
            dis     = new DataInputStream( file );

            numkeys = 0;
            while (( line = dis.readLine()) != null ) {
                line = line.trim();
                if ( !( line.startsWith( "//" )) && ( line.length() != 0 )) {



                    if ( line.startsWith( "!" )) {
                        isreply = true;
                    } else if ( line.startsWith( "." )) {

                        isreply = false;


                        for ( keyword = ( maxkey - numkeys ); keyword < maxkey; keyword++ ) {
                            first[ keyword ]    = minreply;
                            last[ keyword ]     = maxreply - 1;
                        }
                        numkeys     = 0;                        // reset new key count
                        minreply    = maxreply;                 // point at next slot
                    } else {                                    // store the line

                        if ( isreply ) {
                            replies[ maxreply++ ]   = line;
                        } else {
                            keywords[ maxkey++ ]    = " " + line + " ";
                            numkeys++;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        public String[] askquestion( String question, String answer,String returnkeyword) {
            String temp         = new String();
            String remains      = new String();     // remainder of question
            String NOKEYFOUND   = new String( " NOKEYFOUND " );
            int pos;
            int i;
            Character curchar;
            int test;
            boolean addQMark    = false;

            question    = question.toUpperCase();
            for ( i = 0; i < question.length(); ++i ) {
                curchar = new Character( question.charAt( i ));
                test    = curchar.charValue();
                if ((( test >= 'A' ) && ( test <= 'Z' )) ||
                    (( test >= '0' ) && ( test <= '9' )) ||
                    ( test == ' ' )) {

                    temp    = temp + curchar;
                }
            }
            temp    = " " + temp + " ";





            for ( i = 0, pos = 0, keyword = 0; i < maxkey; i++ ) {
                if (( pos = temp.indexOf( keywords[ i ] )) != -1 ) {
                    keyword = i;

                    if (( keyword < maxkey ) &&
                        ( keywords[ keyword ] != NOKEYFOUND )) {
                        remains = temp.substring( pos - 1 + keywords[ i ].length());
                    } else {
                        remains = "";       // ???
                    }
                    break;
                }
            }
            if ( keyword == 0 ) {       // find NOKEYFOUND set
                for ( i = 0; i < maxkey; i++ ) {
                    if ( keywords[ i ].equals( NOKEYFOUND )) {
                        keyword = i;
                        break;
                    }
                }
                remains = "";
            }



                if (keywords[keyword].equals(  " BLUE JERSEY " ))
                    returnkeyword = keywords[keyword];
                else if (keywords[keyword].equals(  " RED JERSEY " ))
                    returnkeyword = keywords[keyword];
                else if (keywords[keyword].equals(  " WHITE JERSEY " ))
                    returnkeyword = keywords[keyword];













               // now get reply using the keyword number

            answer  = replies[ first[ keyword ] + offset[ keyword ]];







            offset[ keyword ]++;
            if ( offset[ keyword ] + first[ keyword ] > last[ keyword ] ) {
                offset[ keyword ] = 0;
            }



            for ( i = 0; i < maxkey; i++ ) {
                if ( first[ i ] == first[ keyword ] ) {
                    offset[ i ] = offset[ keyword ];
                }
            }

            // return the answer

            return new String[]{answer,returnkeyword};

        }
        //return new String[]{answer,returnkeyword};
    }


       }
```

***This is the whole theme-woocommerce.php***

```
<?php
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Any WooCommerce overrides and functions can be found here
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// Check WooCommerce is installed first
add_action('wp_head', 'woostore_check_environment');

function woostore_check_environment() {
 if (!class_exists('woocommerce')) wp_die(__('WooCommerce must be installed',         'woothemes')); 
}

  // Add html5 shim
 add_action('wp_head', 'wootique_html5_shim');
 function wootique_html5_shim() {
 ?>
 <!-- Load Google HTML5 shim to provide support for <IE9 -->
 <!--[if lt IE 9]>
 <script src="https://html5shim.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
 <![endif]-->
<?php
 }

 // Disable WooCommerce styles 
 define('WOOCOMMERCE_USE_CSS', false);

 /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------  */
/* Header
   /*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

//Parameter plugin
global $wp_query;

if (isset($wp_query->query_vars['keyword']))
{
print $wp_query->query_vars['keyword'];
    }



 // Hook in the search
 add_action('woo_nav_before', 'wootique_header_search');
  function wootique_header_search() {
global $woo_options;
?>

<div id="search-top">
        <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo       esc_url( home_url( '/'  ) ); ?>">
        <div>
            <label class="screen-reader-text" for="s"><?php _e( 'Search    for:', 'woocommerce' ); ?></label>
            <input type="text" value="<?php echo get_search_query(); ?>" name="s" id="s" placeholder="<?php _e( 'Search for products', 'woocommerce' ); ?>" />
            <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="query_vars["keyword"]" />
            <input type="hidden" name="post_type" value="product" />
        </div>
    </form>


</div><!-- /.search-top -->
<?php
    }

   add_action('woo_nav_after', 'wootique_cart_button', 10);
   function wootique_cart_button() {
   echo current(woostore_header_add_to_cart_fragment());
   }

   add_action('woo_nav_after', 'wootique_checkout_button', 20);
   function wootique_checkout_button() {
   global $woocommerce;
   ?>
   <ul id="account-nav" class="nav fr">

  <?php
   if (sizeof($woocommerce->cart->cart_contents)>0) :
    echo '<li class="checkout"><a href="'.$woocommerce->cart-   >get_checkout_url().'">'.__('Checkout','woothemes').'</a></li>';
endif; 
?>

   </ul>
  <?php
  }

// Remove WC sidebar
remove_action( 'woocommerce_sidebar', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10);

// Adjust markup on all WooCommerce pages
                               remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content',        'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper', 10);
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_main_content',   'woocommerce_output_content_wrapper_end', 10);

 add_action('woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woostore_before_content', 10);
 add_action('woocommerce_after_main_content', 'woostore_after_content', 20);

   // Fix the layout etc
     function woostore_before_content() {
?>
<!-- #content Starts -->
<?php woo_content_before(); ?>
   <div id="content" class="col-full">

    <!-- #main Starts -->
    <?php woo_main_before(); ?>
    <div id="main" class="col-left">
     <?php
    }
    function woostore_after_content() {
?>    
        <?php if ( is_search() && is_post_type_archive() ) { add_filter(        'woo_pagination_args', 'woocommerceframework_add_search_fragment', 10 ); } ?>
    <?php woo_pagenav(); ?>
    </div><!-- /#main -->
           <?php woo_main_after(); ?>

        </div><!-- /#content -->
    <?php woo_content_after(); ?>
       <?php
       }

    function woocommerceframework_add_search_fragment ( $settings ) {
$settings['add_fragment'] = '&post_type=product';
return $settings;
     } // End woocommerceframework_add_search_fragment()

    // Add the WC sidebar in the right place
    add_action( 'woo_main_after', 'woocommerce_get_sidebar', 10);

  // Remove breadcrumb (we're using the WooFramework default breadcrumb)
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woocommerce_breadcrumb', 20, 0);
  add_action( 'woocommerce_before_main_content', 'woostore_breadcrumb', 01, 0);

   function woostore_breadcrumb() {
global  $woo_options;
if ( $woo_options[ 'woo_breadcrumbs_show' ] == 'true' ) {
    woo_breadcrumbs();
}
    }

   // Remove pagination (we're using the WooFramework default pagination)
   remove_action( 'woocommerce_pagination', 'woocommerce_pagination', 10 );

  // Adjust the star rating in the sidebar
  add_filter('woocommerce_star_rating_size_sidebar', 'woostore_star_sidebar');

  function woostore_star_sidebar() {
return 12;
   }

  // Adjust the star rating in the recent reviews
  add_filter('woocommerce_star_rating_size_recent_reviews', 'woostore_star_reviews');

  function woostore_star_reviews() {
return 12;
  }

  // Change columns in product loop to 3
  add_filter('loop_shop_columns', 'woostore_loop_columns');

  function woostore_loop_columns() {
return 3;
  }

   // Change columns in related products output to 3

     remove_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary',     'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);
    add_action( 'woocommerce_after_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_output_related_products', 20);

  function woocommerce_output_related_products() {
   woocommerce_related_products(3,3); // 3 products, 3 columns
  }

   // Display 12 products per page
  add_filter('loop_shop_per_page', create_function('$cols', 'return 12;'));

 // Move the price below the excerpt on the single product page
  remove_action( 'woocommerce_template_single_summary',     'woocommerce_template_single_price', 10, 2);
   add_action( 'woocommerce_template_single_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_price', 25, 2);

       // Handle cart in header fragment for ajax add to cart
         add_filter('add_to_cart_fragments', 'woostore_header_add_to_cart_fragment');

           function woostore_header_add_to_cart_fragment(  ) {
           global $woocommerce;

$fragments['#btn-cart'] = '
<div id="btn-cart" class="fr">
    <a href="'.$woocommerce->cart->get_cart_url().'" title="'.__('View your shopping   cart', 'woothemes').'">
        <span>'.sprintf(_n('%d item &ndash; ', '%d items &ndash; ',      $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_contents_count(), 'woothemes'), $woocommerce->cart- >get_cart_contents_count()) . $woocommerce->cart->get_cart_total() . '</span>
    </a>
</div>
';

return $fragments;

           }
```

*Edited code theme-woocommerce.php*** (Suggested by miffet)

```
<head profile="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<script type="text/javascript">
this.name = "smartjersionline";
</script> 
</head>

<?php
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/* Any WooCommerce overrides and functions can be found here
/*-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/

// Check WooCommerce is installed first
add_action('wp_head', 'woostore_check_environment');

   function woostore_check_environment() {
 if (!class_exists('woocommerce')) wp_die(__('WooCommerce must be installed',  'woothemes'));
```

}

***Edited Code of java page*** (Suggested by miffet)

```
try {  


                //String data1 = URLEncoder.encode("answer", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(system.askquestion(instring,outstring,getkeyword)[0], "UTF-8");

                //String encodedKW = URLEncoder.encode("keyword", "UTF-8") + "=" + URLEncoder.encode(system.askquestion(instring,outstring,getkeyword)[1], "UTF-8"); 
                //String keywords;
                //String data =   encodedKW ;  

                String encodedKW = URLEncoder.encode(system.askquestion(instring , outstring, getkeyword)[1], "UTF-8");
                String formURL = "http://smartjersionline.owhbisnes.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-template.php"; // this should be whatever home_url() in PHP returns
                URL url = new URL(formURL + "?s=" + encodedKW + "&post_type=product"); // s because there is <input name="s"...> in the form
                getAppletContext().showDocument(url, "smartjersionline"); // the second argument is target window name

                String inLine;  

                URL u1 = new URL("http://localhost/echo.php");
                //URL u1 = new URL("http://smartjersionline.owhbisnes.com/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-template.php" + "?s=" + encodedKW );  
                URLConnection uc1 = u1.openConnection();  

                uc1.setDoOutput(true);  
                OutputStreamWriter out = new OutputStreamWriter(uc1.getOutputStream());  
                out.write(encodedKW); 
                out.flush();  

                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader( new InputStreamReader( uc1.getInputStream() ) );  

                while ((inLine = in.readLine()) != null) {  
                    System.out.println(inLine);  
                }  

                in.close();  
            }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not clear what are you trying to do with the keyword in `theme-woocommerce.php`. I understand it that you are trying to send request as if the form you list in your question was submitted. In that case you don't need `$_POST["keyword"]` because the form has different request variables like "s" (`name="s"`).

Also, the form uses the GET method, so it would be easier for you to put the keyword to the requested URL in the [query string](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string).

And lastly, you don't close the connection in your Java code, that could also be a problem.

---

**Edit:** If the goal is to open URL http://smartjersionline.owhbisnes.com/?s=blue&post_type=product in the original window, than you're trying to do a redirect in the browser from the Java code.

This is beyond my area of expertise. I discovered [this article](http://www.mkyong.com/applet/how-to-redirect-to-a-new-url-in-applet/) though. What is needed is

1. Name the target window. You can do this by putting the following script to the `<head>` section of your webpage ([here](http://smartjersionline.owhbisnes.com/)):

   ```
   <script type="text/javascript">
       this.name = "smartjersionline";
   </script>
   ```
2. In your Java code, call `getAppletContext().showDocument()`:

   ```
   String encodedKW = URLEncoder.encode(system.askquestion(instring , outstring, getkeyword)[1], "UTF-8");
   String formURL = "http://smartjersionline.owhbisnes.com/"; // this should be whatever home_url() in PHP returns
   URL url = new URL(formURL + "?s=" + encodedKW + "&post_type=product"); // s because there is <input name="s"...> in the form
   getAppletContext().showDocument(url, "smartjersionline"); // the second argument is target window name
   ```

   See also [javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/AppletContext.html#showDocument%28java.net.URL,%20java.lang.String%29).

Comment: im trying to use the search function of woocommerce product..the  theme-woocommerce.php will get the parameter which is keyword from java page.

Comment: Mifeet : thank you for your response..that what i mean..

1. User will input the sentence from java page.
2. Java page will process it and send only "Keyword" and at the same time the keyword is send into wordpress search function using woocommerce function.

Comment: How can i pass the parameter to wordpress search form..so that it will turn the page base on the keyword??

Comment: What do you intend to do with the result you get from woocommerce anyway? I'm not that familiar with Wordpress nor woocommerce. Do you have the Wordpress site running anywhere public so that I can try it out? If not, can you post what results you get?

Comment: @Miffet : i already add whole code of java + php page at the bottom of my questions..this is my website that run public 


My website:
http://smartjersionline.owhbisnes.com

at the navigation u can see the avatar. "Ask Faris". U may click it. And then it will pop up the java applet.

u can type at the text field "I want to buy blue jersey"

what i want to do is:
the "blue" keyword will be extracted, and pass the parameter to the search form of "Cari Jersi Anda!" at the right side of the website.


so it will turn the page of required keyword. Can u help me..please..i really need ur help..:(

Comment: So what you really want is not to process the response of woocommerce in the Java code, but to display http://smartjersionline.owhbisnes.com/?s=blue&post_type=product in the original window, right? If that's true, see my updated answer.

Comment: @Miffet: that right..that what i want..i follow your suggestion..but it's still does not turn the page like what i want. I also update the code that i edited in java and also theme-woocommerce.php


could you please check for me..is it correct or not..(above of my question)

Comment: What you did is wrong. If you look at the source code at http://smartjersionline.owhbisnes.com/, you can see that now you have `<head>` there twice. You need to put the script somewhere else. I don't know Wordpress, you need to find out yourself, or ask another question about it at SO. In your "Edited Code of java page (Suggested by miffet)" you don't need anything below the line `getAppletContext()...` (I'm MifEEt, btw). Now it should at least open the page in a new window. That's all I can help you with.

Comment: you are a life saver! Im so sorry to spell your name wrongly..i already follow your code..i paste it into the header.php ..it seem like the header.php in the wordpress is just like index.php ..i run it..yeah! It Really working..thanks man!!

Comment: im sorry to accept and upvote..i need 15 reputation..but now i only have 1 reputation..need more 14..hehe..

Comment: @farisnewbie sorry, I realized you cannot upvote too late. Accept should work, though